# Getting access token and page acces token of facebook pages via passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm building a Node-Express microservice so that my Facebook app can get access to other user pages and post on their behalf. I need the accessToken and pageAccessToken for that which I am using passportjs and passport-facebook
strategy.

I am using the default demo starter code given in passport-facebook github page. I don't know how the done or cb works and where am I getting the User model from.

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport')
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const router = express.Router();
const moment = require('moment');
const axios = require('axios');
const {parse, stringify} = require('flatted/cjs');

const config = require('../config/config');
const constant = require('../config/constants');

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: config.FACEBOOK_ID,
  clientSecret: config.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/facebook/login/status",
  profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'link', 'email']
},  
(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    done(null, user);
  });
}));


router.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['publish_pages', 'manage_pages', 'pages_show_list']
  })     
)

router.get('/login/status', passport.authenticate('facebook',
  (err, user, info) =>  console.log(`user: ${user}`)
), (req,res) => {
  res.send(req.body);
})

module.exports = router;
```

github code: https://github.com/harshdeepkanhai/facebook_access_token
I need accessToken as an object after I login in the callback url.